# Como obter uma palavra a partir de determinada letra dentro de uma String no Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Estou tentando obter uma palavra a partir de determinada letra dentro de uma String no Postgres. Já tentei de diversas maneiras, mas não obtive sucesso usando `substring`, `strpos`…

No select abaixo, eu preciso pegar as palavras que estão dentro da tag `< em >`.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT HISTORICO_MSG FROM TABELA_TESTE
```

Resultado:

```
Campo: <em>Curso de Java<\/em> conteúdo alterado de <em>Listas[id=E]<\/em> para <em>Collections [id=N]<\/em>.<br>
```

Comment: Pesquisou pelas funções de expressões regulares? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

Comment: Tentei algumas funções de regex porém nunca tive contato com isso e estou com dificuldades pra utilizá-lo. Imaginei que pudesse haver algo simples para isso como por exemplo substring(HISTORICO_MSG from '<em>.</em>')